# No me registra en mi base de datos, que fallaria?

Tags: reactjs, mysql-workbench

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  const url = "http://localhost:3000/apiRegistrarse"; //la direccion de mi back para hacer el registro

  const self = this;
  const body = this.getSteps()
  request.post(url, function (error, response, body){
      if (error){
          self.setState({error:true, heAcabado: true})
      } else {
          const parseo = JSON.parse(body);
          self.setState({heAcabado:true})
      }
  }); console.log('acabo el submit');
};

//este es el formulario donde recojo mis datos, los cuales quiero insertar en base de datos

getAccountInformation() {
  return <div>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="form-group">
          <TextField
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            id="userName"
            name='usuario'
            label="UserName"
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="form-group">
          <TextField
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            id="password"
            name='password'
            label={<IntlMessages id="appModule.password"/>}
            type="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Tal como te comentaron, debes ser más específico con lo que quieres que te ayuden. Sabemos que tienes un problema para registrar algo en la base de datos, pero no tenemos más detalles de si está ocurriendo un error, de si los datos se están recibiendo bien, puede incluso ser un problema de autorización, o una mala configuración del servidor, pero debes ser específico con las respuestas que te da el servidor, mensajes de consola, cosas que no funcionan como esperas y etc.